# SGS2 running ICS 4.0.3 can't connect to home wifi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a Samsung Galaxy S II 9100. I had no problem connecting to wifi while it was running 2.3.4 or 2.3.6 official firmware. 2 days ago I upgraded to official 4.0.3 and now it connects to all other wifi networks except my home wireless. I did a clean flash, wiped data, cache, dalvik cache etc. I'm using a Linksys WRT300N wireless-N router and all other devices are able to connect (my laptop, other Android phones). Also, before I installed ICS I tried MIUI 2.3.16 which is based on Android 4.0.3 and had the same problem. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with this router + phone + firmware combo, I found that setting up a DHCP Reservation (using the mac address of your phone) on the router (Setup/Basic Setup/DHCP Server/DHCP Reservation) allowed my phone to connect successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading the wifi driver dial `*#*#526#*#*` (or) install the "[wifi-fixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wahtod.wififixer)" app from the market.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an issue I had forever!

I fixed it by adjusting the router to use **WPA2** only instead of **WPA/WPA2**.  Now all my Android devices connect without problems.

[image]