# SGS2 I9100G keeps disconnecting from WIFI after installing firmware XXLPQ

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-2

2 days ago I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100G from 2.3.6 to 4.0.3 using the firmware XXLPQ. Ever since, my WiFi keeps disconnecting every 10 seconds. I tried all the fixes from this question [SGS2 running ICS 4.0.3 can't connect to home wifi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21088/sgs2-running-ics-4-0-3-cant-connect-to-home-wifi) but it didn't workout for me.

My phone is rooted and I'd do anything to get the Wifi to work again... Help

Comment: Is it from a specific network or this happens everywhere?

Comment: I notice this mostly at home, I have a TP-Link router with WPA2 security. My device has a reserved IP on the router

Answer (score 2):

Well occasionally when you update firmware, your router at home will have problems with the new firmware on your phone (due to out-of-date drivers, old firmware on the router, router is unsupported by new firmware, etc.) So if it works everywhere else pretty well, this might be your issue.

My recommendation: try downloading a different kernel (there are plenty out there for the S2), your best bet looking on the XDA-Forums, maybe start here?

http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=665

Comment: Yup - Kernel's responsible for the WiFi drivers in your phone, so try using another kernel like Siyah.