# Sony Ericsson WT19i doesn't detect my wifi network

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi

When I bought the phone and tried to connect to my wifi network it worked fine, but after 2 days, I don't know why, it just doesn't detect my wifi network.

When I go into `Settings->Wireless & network Settings-> Wi-fi settings` my network doesn't show up there. Lots of other networks appear there but not mine.

I tried configuring manually with SSID WPA/WPA2 PSK and it says not in range. After this I tried rooting phone but still no luck.

I have a Galaxy SII and 2 other computers working correctly with my network. What's causing the WT19i to be unable to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Check this forum out, since you're rooted now:

[SGS2 I9100G keeps disconnecting from WIFI after installing firmware XXLPQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/sgs2-i9100g-keeps-disconnecting-from-wifi-after-installing-firmware-xxlpq/24512#24512)

Try installing a new kernel (usually found on XDA).